# How is the data on the new Google Drive for Desktop stored

Tags: windows, partitioning, google-drive-file-stream

As of recently, Backup and Sync has been merged into a much newer and much more complex application, Google Drive for Desktop. [I use Windows for these examples, btw]. For the most part, the transition was relatively seamless and I was able to get the 2 accounts that I had stored on Backup and Sync merged into Desktop. However, I'm very confused as to how everything's stored now. Like yes there are shortcuts for both my Drives just like with B&S, but one (my main account) is stored on my C:// drive, with a shortcut to an external drive [G://]. Meanwhile, my other account is stored on another external drive [H://], with a shortcut on the drive it was in before [D://].

I suppose these might be several questions in one but I'm really confused as to these rules. I'm trying to answer these questions:

1. **Why did my primary account decide it would be better to keep data on my local drive [C://]?**
   [image]
   --
   [image]

   a. Why did it create a shortcut to this local folder on another drive, seeing as I had never nor would I ever checked or wanted a new drive?

   b. Could I safely delete this drive if I wanted to and how should I [see #3]
2. **Why did my secondary account decide it would be better to move all my data to a new drive [D://]?**
   [image]

   a. Where is this, since I know it's local as I've checked the box for keeping local files?
3. **Why can't I see any of this in diskmgr?**
   [image]

This theoretically should be either a partition of my existing drives, C:// or D://, but as I see it the disk just somehow exists æthereally. WinDirStat sees these drives too, so what is happening here?

Additionally, back in my previous setup of Backup and Sync, I had only selected a subset of my secondary account, since I had a very limited amount of space on [D://]. This was to the point that if I included my entire Drive, it would completely run out of space. However, as I've recently checked in this folder, it seems to magically accommodate the entire drive while also giving me enough space on all my usable drives. This leads me to believe that the files aren't actually stored locally, but in my settings I have set that they can be stored locally and turning off wifi, I can still find it. Could someone shed some light on exactly how this file storage is being done?

Sorry for this long rant, I've just been very confused but any help is definitely appreciated! Thanks all.

Comment: They are not physical disks, it’s a folder, that’s been assigned a drive letter by mounting it.  That is at least the reason disk management doesn’t show them

Comment: How could I find the exact location of these folders?

Comment: Should be in the list of folders being synchronized

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using "mirror" mode (as opposed to streaming), your files are located in C:\Users[your name]\Google Drive.  If you are syncing to Google Drive in more than one account, your second account's files will be located in a directory with a name something like this. C:\Users[your name]\Google Drive (xxxx@gmail.com)

Again, assuming "mirror mode," you can just ignore the "virtual drives" that have been created. They are redundant.