# Increasing drive partition size for Google Drive cloud sync

Tags: windows, partitioning, google-drive-file-stream

I've asked in a [previous post](https://superuser.com/q/1671497/676012) how Google Drive partitions are stored, but I'm having trouble with one particular action. A lot of uploads that I do to my drive are around 1GB-20GB, and although I have space for these files in my Drive online, I am unable to upload them through Google Drive for Desktop since the drive that is remotely synced is too small (about 12GB).

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what the used space amount is, as I have about 1.4TB of files stored in Drive, and 0.6TB left of free space, but either way I'm unable to upload bigger files to this drive. Because this isn't a real partition but rather just a fake partitioning of my hard drive, I can't reallocate memory in diskmgr. Is there any way to increase the size of this free space?

Comment: Are you using mirror or "streaming" mode?  If mirror, what happens when you copy file into C:\Users\[your name]\Google Drive?

Comment: I am using streaming mode. so, when I try to copy a file too big, it simply says "H does not have enough space, needs x more gb". this isn't my C drive Google account; it's a D drive thing, which as I've figured out stores on a different drive with a shortcut stored in D drive.